# Detect if armourstand have nothing on head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Detect if armourstand have nothing on head?
i am making map where peaople can place armourstand into armourstand and i want to repair it with peaople grab the head and then they can grab it from another on one block but firt i need to kill armourstand without the head i am using java edition 1.16.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but this might solve your issue. You can test if the armor stand does not have a player head:

```
execute if entity @e[type=armor_stand,nbt=!{ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:player_head"}]},sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

Comment: wow Thanks  you are the best

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't believe there is really a way to test that, but here is a list of things you can do:

1. Make the armor unbreakable:

   /give {player} {item} {amount} {Unbreakable:1}

Ex:

```
/give Player iron_boots 1{Unbreakable:1}
```

2. Let the player buy whatever item they need to repair the armor
3. Replace the armor every few minutes:

   /replaceitem {player} slot.armor.{Feet,Chest, Etc} {Item}

Ex:

```
/replaceitem Player slot.armor.head diamond_helmet
```

You can repeat that command for every armor slot using a command block.

That's all I can think of at the moment, but I hope it helps! If you have any additional questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: And something the armourstand with helmet cant be killed ?

Comment: And what if i make something with hat it can give some effect no ?

Comment: You can give it an effect.

Comment: 1.16.5 java edition